# ¿Cómo mostrar datos de json_encode codificado con base64_encode?

Tags: php

Tengo datos desde un `array`

```
$data_value=[];
while(...){
   $data_value[] = [
     'name' => $values,
     'name1' => $values,
     'name2' => $values,
     'name3' => null
   ];
}
```

Donde mediante `json_encode($data_value);` guardo los datos para imprimirlos en un pequeño script de `javascript`.

De la siguiente forma los datos se muestran corretamente.

```
<script>
   var data_value = <?php echo json_encode($data_value); ?>;
</script>

<div id="data_value"></div>
```

## Mi alternativa que deseo aplicar.

Mediante el uso de `base64_encode` y `json_encode`

```
<?php
   $values_json = base64_encode(json_encode($data_value));
?>
```

no me muestra los datos.

```
<script>
   var data_value = window.atob('<?php echo $values_json; ?>');
</script>
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos usando esta codificación de la misma forma como se muestra en la alternativa primaria?

Comment: var data_value = <?php echo base64_decode($values_json); ?>;

Comment: @Carmen No me ayuda esa opción la idea es que esos datos no sea fácil de leer para el usuario, al hacerlo de esa forma es como tener los datos como la primera opción que estaba trabajando.

Comment: no está claro lo que quieres, lo lógico es enviar los datos codificados y descodificarlos en destino (preriflemente en php para que no sea accesible), pero estás pidiendo que los muestre igual que en la primera alternativa?? es decir que los enseñe. window.atob si funcionara haría lo mismo, de hecho lo hace si coficas un string en javascript con window.btoa. Para codificar en php y decodifar en javascript necesitas una clase intermedia, aquí tienes un ejemplo para strings https://www.coditty.com/code/utf-base64-encode-in-php-and-decode-in-javascript.

Comment: Si la idea es esconder datos al usuario, no tiene el menor sentido hacerlo con base64. Si lo escondes de alguien que va a buscar el datos, le toma 2 segundos reconocer que es base64 y 2 mas en ponerlo en un conversor online que lo decodifica.

Comment: @Carmen Yo había utilizado antes esta opción `window.atob` de esta manera echo "var data_url = window.atob('".base64_encode($url)."'); "; donde al ver el código fuente no mostraba la URL si no un código codificado, pero al usarlo con datos de `json_encode` no funciona, en el anterior se ejecutaba correctamente en un iframe esa url codificada, pero en `json_encode` no me muestra datos, creo que no se codifica o descodifica con `window.atob()` de manera correcta.

Comment: @Juan No son datos sensibles es decir que no son datos de riesgos... Pero si me gustaría codificarlos aunque yo se que  es fácil su de-codificación pero de todas formas me gusta la idea de implementarlo.

Comment: @Stevin creo que en principio .atob y .btoa se utilizan para strings, quizás alguien que sepa más pueda orientarnos. Puedes probar con el ejemplo del enlace que te pasé por si te sirve para decodificar.